# Nested quantifiers order?

Tags: quantifiers

> $$a) \quad \forall x\exists y(3x+4y=12)$$
>   $$b) \quad \exists x\forall y(3x+4y=12)$$

Am I correct in saying that a) is correct while b) is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are perfectly correct. The order of the quantifiers does matter (assuming $x$ and $y$ belong to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: can you explain in this specific context, why the order matters?

Comment: Well, in the first line, for any value of $x$, you must find $y$ so that $3x+4y=12$, which is obviously possible. However, in the second case, you need to find a value of $x$ for which the equation holds for any value of $y$, which is impossible.